# JS Google Cloud Function Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is a Google Cloud Function in JS and I am getting the following error, the function creates the Stripe customer successfully but it fails to write back to the database.

I am guessing it has something to do with `snap.uid`, am I correct? and how do I get the `uid` of the `User` node that has been created to trigger the function?

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in
>   property

```
exports.createStripeCustomerFromUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const userSnap = snap.val(); 

  const first = userSnap.firstName;
  const last = userSnap.lastName;
  const email = userSnap.email;
  const description = first + ' ' + last;

  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: email,
    description: description,
    name: description,
  }).then((customer) => {
    var updatedUserData = {};
    updatedUserData[`/stripe_ids/${customer.id}`] = snap.uid;
    updatedUserData[`/stripe_customers/${snap.uid}/customer_id`] = customer.id;
    return admin.database().ref().update(updatedUserData);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, use

```
context.params.userId
```

with `userId` came from

```
ref('/users/{userId}')
```